# How to avoid code duplication in this Javascript code snippet

Tags: javascript, function, dom-manipulation, code-duplication

I have tried to add, remove and toggle classstyles to  3 `<li>` s  when  user click on 3 buttons having ids 'add' 'delete' and 'toggle' respectively. But  the codes repeat itself other than the classList method name and button id.

is there anyway i could write a function to avoid repetition?

here is my code.

```
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('#todos li').forEach((li)=>{
        li.classList.add('listStyles');
    })
});
document.querySelector('#delete').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('#todos li').forEach((li)=>{
        li.classList.remove('listStyles');
    })
});
document.querySelector('#toggle').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('#todos li').forEach((li)=>{
        li.classList.toggle('listStyles');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
function modifyClass(action) {
    document.querySelectorAll('#todos li').forEach((li)=>{
        li.classList[action]('listStyles');
    })
}

document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', ()=>{ modifyClass("add") });
document.querySelector('#delete').addEventListener('click', ()=>{ modifyClass("remove") });
document.querySelector('#toggle').addEventListener('click', ()=>{ modifyClass("toggle") });
```

If you changed the element `#delete` to `#remove`, you could do:

```js
for (const action of ["add", "remove", "toggle"])
    document.getElementById(action).addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        document.querySelectorAll('#todos li').forEach((li)=>{
            li.classList[action]('listStyles');
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can use array to remove more redundancy. +1

Comment: Great idea, but `#delete` needs to be changed to `#remove`.

Comment: i have tried the for of loop method. but  the last action (in this case 'toggle') got applied  to every button

Comment: You are right. I forgot to put `let` or `const` before `action`, so `action` ended up in the global scope. I edited my question.

Comment: ohh i see. i added  a function inside loop and and it works now

Comment: You just needed to put `const` in `for (const action of `.